# Naming a Sagemaker Processing job using Sagemaker Pipelines ProcessingStep

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a Sagemaker Pipeline with the current processor:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor


framework_version = "0.23-1"

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version=framework_version,
    instance_type=processing_instance_type,
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name="pre-processing-job-name",
    role=role
)
```

and the processing step is:

```
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep


step_process = ProcessingStep(
    name="AbaloneProcess",
    processor=sklearn_processor,
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=input_data, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
    ],
    code="abalone/preprocessing.py",
)
```

It looks like the base_job_name does nothing, because the processing job that is created is `pipelines-o6e2jn38g05j-AbaloneProcess-nc2OlXF8jA`.

I want the processing job name to be defined manually. Does Sagemaker pipelines support this? I seem to be going around in circles.

Comment: Is there still no real solution to this? My problem is that a huge list of processing jobs makes it difficult to spot which user started one. I'd like to edit the processing job name such that the name of the user is in it too..

Answer (score 2):

Pipelines [sets the processing job name](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/dev/src/sagemaker/workflow/steps.py#L539-L548) to preserve caching behavior.

An override could be added here to allow manually defining job names, but that has been intentionally left out. Because SageMaker job names must be unique, this would become a sharp edge for users who statically define the name without realizing that any pipeline execution after the first will fail with `ResourceAlreadyExists`.

I'd suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues) explaining the usecase and see if the team picks it up.